# Remove Dollar Sign in WPF DataGridTextColumn StringFormat=C

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

When I set the StringFormat=c, the AMOUNT column below displays value with $ which is not what I want as I am dealing with multiple currencies in the table.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AMOUNT, StringFormat=c}" Header="Amount" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Question
1. How can remove the $ sign from the datagrid?
2. More generally, how do I find out the available values for StringFormat? Checked the MSDN Library and I could not find the dictionary of values applicable to StringFormat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StringFormat=n` instead of `StringFormat=c`

see: http://pdmlab.com/samples/

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 2: The following link shows a list of predefined format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer to question 1: The following link explains how to build custom format strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx